# Existing LINQ to Entities queries throw exception on upgrade to VS 2017

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, visual-studio-2017

We recently upgraded our visual studio from 2013 to 2017, are working on with EntityFramework 6.1.3, and with the upgrade have our projects targetting the 4.7 .NET Framework.  With these changes we have existing LINQ queries that are breaking on us.

A simplified example:

```
Dim comm = Communication.Where(Function (t) t.Id = 1).ToList()
Dim query = (From cc In comm
             Let a = ""
             Select New With {
                             .UserName = (From e In Employee
                                       Where e.Initials = cc.EmployeeInitials 
                                       Select ee.UserName).FirstOrDefault()
             }
            )
```

In this situation the result will be a System.NotSupportedException with the message being:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Company.Core.Models.Communication get_cc()'
```

Now removing the Let statement from the query fixes the exception and the query will run fine, however I cannot determine why the Let causes problems and more specifically why this query only recently broke.

So I am hoping someone can give a explanation of why this exception cropped up in VS 2017 when it had worked fine in VS 2013 and in our production system for years.

Comment: Is communication from dbContext ??

Comment: This is from ObjectContext.